# Python - Is there any way to create nested Enum class from distinct value of column in database dynamically?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm developing REST APIs using python framework called FASTAPI.
I want to get available values for Parameter **ym** from distinct value of column in database automatically.
For example:

```
class Enum_YM(str, Enum):
    Y2021M06 = "2021-06"
    Y2021M07 = "2021-07"
    Y2021M08 = "2021-08"
    Y2021M09 = "2021-09"
```

And get available values for Parameter **q** conditioned on value of Parameter **ym** dynamically.
For example:

```
class Enum_Q(str, Enum):
    Y2021M07Q1 = "sub1"
    Y2021M07Q2 = "sub2"
    Y2021M07Q3 = "sub3"
```

**Update:** The code below is which I'm trying to create class for parameters, which works for me. I can get available values, but can't restrict available values for parameter **q** by specifying value of parameter **ym**.

```
class Enum_YM(str, Enum):
    pass

class Enum_Q(str, Enum):
    pass

def read_classYM(Enum_YM):
    db = SessionLocal()
    qr_ym = db.query(models.name_of_table.column_contains_ym).distinct().all()
    aa = { 'Y' + str(ym[0]).replace("-","M"): ym[0] for ym in qr_ym}
    aa = sorted(aa.items())
    Enum_YM = Enum_YM("yms", aa)
    return Enum_YM

def read_classQ(Enum_Q):
    db = SessionLocal()
    qr_ym = db.query(models.name_of_table.column_contains_ym).distinct().all()
    ww = {}
    for ym in qr_ym:
        qr_word = db.query(models.name_of_table.column_contains_q).filter(models.name_of_table.column_contains_ym == ym[0]).distinct().all()
        ww = {**ww, **{ 'Y' + str(ym[0]).replace("-","M") + 'W' + str(i) : word[0] for i, word in enumerate(qr_word, start=1)}}
    ww = sorted(ww.items())
    Enum_Q = Enum_Q("q", ww)
    return  Enum_Q

Enum_YM = read_classYM(Enum_YM)
Enum_Q = read_classQ(Enum_Q)
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjdwk.png)

Comment: Maybe something like [Enum's functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) can help.

Comment: @rchome thx a lot. With get_classYM(), I can get Enum_YM successfully, but the response is []. The API works fine when I create Enum_YM manually.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking about here. You give two functions as examples, but you don't say what is wrong with them, if anything. Are you getting an exception? Wrong behavior? Give more details! It seems there's some kind of relation between your two enums, but I don't understand what it is supposed to be.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for your patience. I'm try to create a route responses stats monthly, there are three unqiue value of q for every ym(year-month), I want to restrict available values for parameter q when I specify the value of parameter ym.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.